# Set routes in Kohana

Tags: php, model-view-controller, kohana

If I defined 2 controllers, A.php and B.php, and in each controller I defined an index action,
how should I define `Route::set` in the bootstrap.php file?

Comment: Have you tried to read documentation: http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/kohana/routing?

Comment: this comment must be accepted as the best answer ))

Answer (score 3):

The default route should do just fine:

```
Route::set('default', '(<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))')
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'welcome',
        'action'     => 'index',
    ));
```

Please read the documentation: http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/kohana/routing

That default route will match both controller '/a' and controller '/b', and execute the index action if no other action is specified in the URI.

Answer (score 1):

I have read the documentation and it's not completely clear when and why you would want to create a Route entry.

Basically, a Route entry is needed if you have a URL that does not conform to the normal /controller/action structure. If you have created controller A and controller B both with index actions, you don't need to add routes to bootstrap.php if you are always going to access those actions using the standard URL syntax:

```
http://www.example.com/A/index
http://www.example.com/B/index
```

You could leave off "index" since it is the default action if none is specified.

Let's say you want controller A to be the default site controller, meaning that you don't want to have to use A in the URL, you want to use the action right after the domain:

```
http://www.example.com/index
```

Then you do need a route to tell Kohana that any URL that is not matched by any routes you have created (or if you have none) should be handled by your default route. You would create this route in bootstrap.php:

```
Route::set('default', '(<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))')
     ->defaults(array(
          'controller' => 'A',
          'action' => 'index'
     ));
```

This says that if a user goes to http://www.example.com, Kohana will use the index action of controller A. If the user goes to http://www.example.com/foo, then Kohana will use the foo action of controller A. Any URL that does not match any other controller will go to the A controller. If a user requests an action that A does not handle, he'll get a 404 exception.

You still have the B controller, so that will work fine without any route. If the user goes to http://www.example.com/B/index, Kohana knows about the B controller in the app so it will go to the index action there.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem may be in .htaccess file in kohana folder. 
I needed to change the "RewriteBase" to the Kohana folder ('base_url' from Kohana::init in bootstrap.php file), otherwise I landed in '404 - no object found'.
Then the default route should do just fine.